# How to share the same postgres database between 2 Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

We plan to have 2 Rails 3.2 app accessing ONE postgres database for security reasons. Are there something we need to give a special consideration or to do when 2 apps accessing the same database. BTW we are not deploying to heoku.

Comment: Are they sharing models or just the database? I suspect that avoiding migration and model name conflicts would be the biggest issues.

Comment: Some tables are shared by both apps. For example, user table will be shared by both apps. Migration probably should be in one app only. Some other tables are for one app only.

Comment: But if only one app is handling the migrations then you effectively have all your models in only one app. I tend to view the database as an entirely separate application (whose API is SQL) but that doesn't really mesh that well with how Rails wants to do things.

Comment: Actually, NO. Both apps will have its own migrations.